# Well water pressure issue

Tags: plumbing

I have a new well-3 weeks now. Have had pressure issues and they had to blow it out twice. Now when I run a garden hose-25 ft- I notice the pressure gauge drops to 40 , clicks then continues to drop. They tell me it's the length of the hose. If I try to run 2 hoses which they told me to do to flush it ( water was brown) I can't. Is this normal?  It is a 1 hp pump.

Comment: You may have dirty water for a while and when seasons change , going from a low summer water table to a higher winter level, and even after an extended heavy draw on the well this is normal until all the loose sediment is flushed out. It sounds like you may be flushing for a while but it usually clears up. I put string filters on new wells to keep the debris out of the system. It sounds like the sediment is causing your problem and the pump is not able to get enough water, at 300' I would say a 1HP may be a bit small and with the sediment be part of the pressure drop problem, time will tell

Comment: How deep is your well?  Submersible / jet or shallow well pump?  Submersible is inside the well,  Or in the cellar, jet pump two pipes, shallow well pump one pipe.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the pressure switch clicks "ON" and the pump starts, the pressure gauge should start to rise unless you are pumping a lot of water (more than 1 hose connected). Is this a submersible pump down in the well or a jet type pump mounted in the home. How deep is the well and at what depth did they hit the water table ? The water may turn brown until the dirt dirt is removed from the well which in my experience is about 1 or 2 days. You said that they had to "blow it out twice". What does that mean. Lastly, after they drilled the well, did they use a bailer to tell the capacity of the well they just dug and how much capacity does this well have. They should have these answers.

Comment: I have no idea regarding the  last part of your answer. They drilled 370 ft. I was told the shape fell in and they could then go only 325 ft and that my pump is at 300 ft. It is submersible. My water turned brown and they told me to run 2-3 hoses to flush it. I could only run one so they had to get the rig out twice to blown air down the pipe to clean the acreen. Now it seems to hold at 40 with one hose running but drops if I crack another open. My water was brown again today so turned the hoses on.  Seems to me if they tell me to run 2 hoses they feel like the pump should handle it?